# POST action passing null ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, viewmodel

I know this question has been asked and answered a dozen of times but none of the solutions help me.

I have a following ViewModel which is consisted of ProductDetail data model and a list of Product_ProductCategoryAttribute data model.

```
public class ProductDetailViewModel
{
    public ProductDetail ProductDetail { get; set; }
    public List<Product_ProductCategoryAttribute> Product_ProductCategoryAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

On an action postback I receive an empty ViewModel.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "idProductDetail,idProductCategory,idProduct,Name,Description")] ProductDetailViewModel productDetailAll)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProductDetail productDetail = productDetailAll.ProductDetail;
            db.Entry(productDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(productDetailAll);
    }
```

However, as I believe that the underlying problem is somewhere within the view I will add the view code snippet.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ProductDetail", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProductDetail.idProductDetail)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDetail.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductDetail.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ProductDetail.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ProductDetail.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Product_ProductCategoryAttribute.Count(); i++)
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">@Model.Product_ProductCategoryAttribute[i].ProductCategoryAttribute.Name</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Product_ProductCategoryAttribute[i].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>
        }

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

HTML generated from the view above is as follows (some parts are ommited for brevity):

```
<form action="/Administration/ProductDetail/Edit/4" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="IS4fstTTjOD4d9FEzyM5yWlvO9xqlOq_AHFx_8_vC079F1iDvucf5wgRIgV4iXH-NGU-u-J8IHBiKT4ApvR3cSLbhw_AntbibEFsD68eUkc1" />
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field idProductDetail must be a number." data-val-required="The idProductDetail field is required." id="ProductDetail_idProductDetail" name="ProductDetail.idProductDetail" type="hidden" value="4" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ProductDetail_Name">Name</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="ProductDetail_Name" name="ProductDetail.Name" type="text" value="Čipka i hiljadu šara" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="ProductDetail_Description">Description</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <input htmlAttributes="{ class = form-control }" id="ProductDetail_Description" name="ProductDetail.Description" type="text" value="Šipka i čipka" />
            </div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Veličina</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Product_ProductCategoryAttribute_0__Value" name="Product_ProductCategoryAttribute[0].Value" type="text" value="" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Širina</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Product_ProductCategoryAttribute_1__Value" name="Product_ProductCategoryAttribute[1].Value" type="text" value="" />
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Pakiranje</label>
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <input class="form-control" id="Product_ProductCategoryAttribute_2__Value" name="Product_ProductCategoryAttribute[2].Value" type="text" value="" />
                </div>

            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm not sure if something is wrong with the naming convention but my bet would be on that.

Comment: What is the method you are posting back to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke It is really basic - it doesn't do anything (yet) but accepting **ProductDetailViewModel**

Comment: Show it. The controls are named correctly so the error is in you controller method. Could be a number of reasons, but best guess is you have named the parameter the same name as one of your model properties.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Even though I've been coping with this for the past two days I've found the problem. Autogenerated [Bind(Include="")] - will edit the post. You were right - controller was the problem.

Comment: You should edit your question with the controller and add an answer (as it is, this question is a bit useless to anyone else)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Already done ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in autogenerated controller Edit action which added couple of **[Bind(Include="")]** attributes which were wrong and which were preventing data to be posted to the server.

Correct snippet would look like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit (ProductDetailViewModel productDetailAll)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ProductDetail productDetail = productDetailAll.ProductDetail;
        db.Entry(productDetail).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(productDetailAll);
}
```