# all my textboxes return null what should I do?

Tags: asp.net, razor, model-view-controller, null, html.textboxfor

I have a problem here with regards to elements on my pages returning `null` even though I have typed something in the textbox. What causes this? I want to make a simple CRUD app with a dashboard for final year.

Here is my view:

```
@model WebApplication1.Models.Category

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Category";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class 
        ="control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = 
            new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { 
            @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
} 

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Here is my controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Name")] Category category)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Categories.Add(category);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(category);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to post to the correct ActionName. You use `@using (Html.BeginForm())`, which will post to the Index of a Controller. But you have `Create`. So point the form to that.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have proper viewmodel properties setup first:

```
public class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then point to action name and controller name which handles POST action in `BeginForm` helper:

```
@* assumed the controller name is 'CategoryController' *@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Category", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // form contents
}
```

And finally change parameter name to avoid naming conflict in default model binder, also remove `BindAttribute` because the POST action has strongly-typed viewmodel class as parameter:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Category model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Categories.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Related issue:

[POST action passing null ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532758/post-action-passing-null-viewmodel)

Comment: hey guys thanks a lot for the help it turns out I was using the wrong namespace for the controller (because I copy pasted the page) .