# Server Error in '/' with Validation in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

There always a Server Error in '/'Application. when I try to use a validation check in the web application.

This is the Model:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVCDemon.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
    [DisplayName("MovieName")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings =false, ErrorMessage ="CanNotBeEmpty")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MVCDemon.Models;

namespace MVCDemon.Controllers
{
    public class MovieController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Validation(Movie movie)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ViewBag.Name = movie.Name;
            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Html:

```
<div>
@model MVCDemon.Models.Movie
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}
</div>
<div>
    @ViewBag.Name
</div>
```

And this is for the layout:

[image]

I checked the Scripts and I do import the jquery.validation.min.js and jquery.validation.unobtrusive.min.js

Also, I tried to set the config as someone mentioned:

[image]

But the error still there.

> Server Error in '/' Application. The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its
>   dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is
>   temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make
>   sure that it is spelled correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [all my textboxes return null what should I do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385368/all-my-textboxes-return-null-what-should-i-do)

Comment: A 404 has nothing to do with validation. See the duplicate. You probably are not posing to the correct controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is meaning of error 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658375/what-is-meaning-of-error-404-not-found)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your form is not being routed to the controller.

You can do this by adding the below parameters to the `Html.BeginForm`:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Validation", "Movie", FormMethod.Post))
{
    // ...rest of form code
}
```

The important parameters are `actionName`, `controllerName`.

Comment: note that if `Html.BeginForm()` is left empty as OP has it, then it will look for a post action with the same name as the view that the html helper is written in. hard to tell if this is his issue since he hasn't specified the name of the view but I'm guessing this answer will fix this OP's issue. Just wanted to point that out

Comment: @GregH Very true, without the get method though I can't deduce from that. If it was the same the conventions would pick it up and it wouldn't be a 404.

Comment: @GregH Thank you so much for answering the question! I tried to fix it through the parameters in the BeginForm(actionName, controllerName) as you mentioned. Unfortunately, the problem still there. But, your comment inspired me about the POST action. I just delete the annotation of controller [HttpPost] from the method, then everything is good. I m still confusing about that... why I can not use that annotation to declare?

Comment: @YANQINGJING did you include `FormMethod.Post` in the `Html.BeginForm(...)` as well? @hutchonoid 's answer definitely works so I'm guessing you were missing something in your original attempt at implementing his suggestion

Comment: @YANQINGJING Yes, you need to include the `FormMethod.Post`. You want to post the form, by removing it you are changing it to an httpget.

Comment: @GregH Yes, I include the FormMethod.Post in the BeginForm(). And I found, the program is working whether I add all parameters or not (empty parameters). The web page will display that error only when I add an annotation [HttpPost] for the controller.

Comment: @YANQINGJING that doesn't make any sense to me... I feel like youre leaving something out. Any one else able to shed some light on why this would be happening?

Comment: @YANQINGJING Please provide your `[HttpGet]` code i.e. how your view is being rendered in the first place.

Comment: @hutchonoid Thank you so much for your advice! There is no [HttpGet] method before actually. After you told me about that, I add a [HttpGet] method in the controller. I set the breakpoint to each method, and I found each time when the web page is loading, the [HttpGet] method will be first called. Only after submitting data through the form, the [HttpPost] method will be invoked. It seems that the web page can not be loaded if there is only no [HttpGet] method. So, when I delete the annotation [HttpPost] and only left one method, the default action will help me to load the page(guess?).

Comment: @YANQINGJING No problem. I'd recommend having the two the first [httpget] which initially loads the page and returns an initialized model. Then the [httppost] for when the form and model is submitted back.

Comment: @YANQINGJING it would be something simple like: `
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Validation()
        {
     var model = new Movie();
            return View(model);
        }`